# How can I retrieve similar Orders having exact matching itemSku In Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
ID    OrderNumber         
1     123456                 
2     234567                    
3     345678                    
4     456789
```

```
***PurchasedProductsTable***
OrderId     itemSku     
1           1001     
1           1002     
2           1001     
3           1001     
3           1002     
4           1001
```

In the above table I pass `itemSku` value and the query should retrieve only that `itemSku` containing similar orders (in `purchasedProducts` table).

Here if I pass 1001, it matches the `itemSKu` (1001) in order id 2 and 4 so order 2 and 4 are retrieved not containing other `itemSku` as order id 2 and 4 contains that 1001 sku only.

If I run query again with item sku 1001 and 1002 it should retrieve similar orders of 1 and 3 as order 1 and 3 contains both sku 1001 and 1002.

What I did is trying query like this but it is not working as expected it also retrieve others non matching orders.

```
SELECT 
    o.id, 
    o.orderNumber 
FROM 
    OrdersTable o
    INNER JOIN PurchasedProductsTable p ON p.orderId = o.id 
WHERE 
    p.itemSku IN ('1001') 
GROUP BY 
    p.orderId HAVING COUNT(p.itemSku) = ? 
ORDER BY 
    o.created_at DESC
```

Comment: Something to think about: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdtk6EnvAkUodUFcMiwHhj/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT o.ID, o.OrderNumber
FROM Orders o
JOIN PurchasedProductsTable ppt ON o.ID = ppt.OrderId
CROSS JOIN ( {SKUs list as a rowset, i.e. SELECT .. UNION SELECT ..} ) sku
GROUP BY o.ID, o.OrderNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ppt.itemSku) = SUM(ppt.itemSku = sku.sku)
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT sku.sku) = SUM(ppt.itemSku = sku.sku)
```

or

```sql
SELECT o.ID, o.OrderNumber
FROM Orders o
JOIN PurchasedProductsTable ppt ON o.ID = ppt.OrderId
CROSS JOIN ( {SKUs list as a rowset} ) sku
GROUP BY o.ID, o.OrderNumber
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ppt.itemSku ORDER BY ppt.itemSku) = GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sku.sku ORDER BY sku.sku)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f12e0e4d401946b5617f74da8eb311a0

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: If DISTINCT is necessary here, that would point to larger problems with the present schema. And not defining primary keys renders this answer incomplete

Comment: *If DISTINCT is necessary here* For `ppt.itemSku` it not needed if `PurchasedProductsTable (OrderId, itemSku)` is defined as unique. For `sku.sku` it not needed if dups absense in the criteria list is guaranteed.

Comment: @akina . SKUs list as a rowset ? can u privide me a static sample data. i am finding hard time to generate it statically as i will pass that value manually !. thanks

Comment: @imDevD *i will pass that value manually* What is precise data providing form? In my solution the list must be a rowset (or must be converted to rowset) - what is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @akina its 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2 . can u give me example of data set that is going be like here ? specific to {SKUs list as a rowset} this. ?

Comment: @imDevD I don't understand your question. See fiddle - in it the `{SKUs list as a rowset}` placeholder is replaced with the criteria specified in your question in rowset form.

Comment: @Akina {SKUs list as a rowset} means something like CROSS JOIN ( {'1001', '1002'} ) sku instead of {SKUs list as a rowset} ??

Comment: @imDevD Look at the fiddle by the link provided.

Comment: @Akina i will pass 1001 and 1002 itemSku from frontend to api for query so i dont need to do query like SELECT .. UNION SELECT .. in db. so how can i format my item Sku list  to rowset {SKUs list as a rowset} to do query ??

Comment: *so i dont need to do query like SELECT .. UNION SELECT .. in db* You must. All techniques which converts CSV values list to rowset either are too complex or needs 8.0.4+ version.

Comment: Please add a plain English explanation to this code-only answer for the benefit of the OP and thousands of future researchers.